# Update the values of a file using information from another file

Tags: text-processing, awk, bioinformatics

File 1:

```
P       SNP:
0.266234        1:11008
0.266234        1:11012
0.340042        1:13110
0.86724 rs201725126
0.86724 rs200579949
0.127269        1:1327
```

File 2:

```
snp     chr:pos
rs201725126     1:10020
rs200579949     1:10055
rs62651026      1:10108
rs376007522     1:10109
rs796688738     1:10128
rs368469931     1:10139
```

Desired output:

```
P       SNP:
0.266234        1:11008
0.266234        1:11012
0.340042        1:13110
0.86724 1:10020
0.86724 1:10055
0.127269        1:13273
```

So, I would like to replace all rsIDs in file one with chr:pos from file 2, keeping all other lines that already have chr:pos format inact.

I have tried this command:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2} NR>FNR{$2=a[$2];print}'  file2.txt file1.txt > merged.txt
```

Although it merges the rsIDs well, I lose the existing chr:pos format, as shown below.

```
P       SNP:
0.266234        
0.266234        
0.340042        
0.86724 1:10020
0.86724 1:10055
0.127269
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} $2 in a {$2=a[$2]} {print}'  file2.txt file1.txt
P       SNP:
0.266234        1:11008
0.266234        1:11012
0.340042        1:13110
0.86724 1:10020
0.86724 1:10055
0.127269        1:1327
```